# jQuery select value color

Tags: jquery

I have a select drop down and I change the color of the selected value using the following code:

```
if(some condition)
{
   $j("#" + myddlId + " option:selected").css('color', 'red');
}
```

The problem is that when I select the value for e.g. apples from dropdown. Apples being the displayed value in the dropdown is red. But now if I click on the dropdown I can see apples in the option list as red. I don't want that.

Please tell me a way to achieve this using jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

set the "select" color to change the selectbox and the "option" color to the default color of your select

example :

```
 if(some condition)
 {
     $j("#" + myddlId).css('color', 'red');
     $j("#" + myddlId + " option").css('color', 'black');
 }
```

live example : http://jsfiddle.net/yQvLJ/

Comment: I will make an example in a while

Answer (score 1):

can you not remove 'color' property on drop down list click?

Comment: no..i need it red for the selected value but otheerwise in the list it should not be dispalyed red...

Comment: Enclose dropdown list in a div and see if you can reset the item colors on a onClick event on div.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible just by using simple `select` element. You can take a look at this plugin, I think it will help you considering your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood the problem properly, you can try this:

```
if(some condition)
{
  $j("#" + myddlId).css('color', 'black');
  $j("#" + myddlId + " option:selected").css('color', 'red');
}
```

Comment: i already have that line in my code...i just did not add it here..exactly the same line :)..it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Removing the CSS class when you click the dropdown is the way to go.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G7VKt/9/) that illustrates how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the color of `select` to red and all the `options` to black - http://jsfiddle.net/UzWbf/